# как сделать задержку svg animate with Snap.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, animate, snapsvg

Как сделать, чтобы линии поочереди выполняли анимацию? 
Еще интересует, как можно такую анимацию делать максимально просто. В правильном ли я направлении? Мне еще нужно отрисовать линию к кнопке

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // SVG animate
    var s = Snap("#svg1");

    var line = s.path("M 0 0 L 360 0");
    var line_hover = s.path("M 0 0 L 0 0");

    line_hover.attr({
        fill: "transparent",
        stroke: "#4054b2",
        strokeWidth: 5
    });

    line.attr({
        fill: "#000",
        stroke: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
        strokeWidth: 5
    });
    line_hover.animate({d: "L 360 0"}, 3000);

    var s2 = Snap("#svg2");

    var line2 = s2.path("M 0 0 L 360 0");
    var line2_hover = s2.path("M 0 0 L 0 0");

    line2_hover.attr({
        fill: "transparent",
        stroke: "#4054b2",
        strokeWidth: 5
    });

    line2.attr({
        fill: "#000",
        stroke: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
        strokeWidth: 5
    });
    line2_hover.animate({d: "L 360 0"}, 6000);
});
```

```css
.connection__wrap {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.connection__content{
        display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 90px 0;
}
.connection__content-item {
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}
.connection__content-item-img {
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
    margin: 0 auto 26px;
    position: relative;
        border-radius: 50%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
}
.connection__content-item-img.pink {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,right top,left top,from(#F64A89),to(#D81B60));
    background: linear-gradient(to left,#F64A89,#D81B60);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(216,27,96,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(216,27,96,.5);
}
.connection__content-item-img.orange {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,right top,left top,from(#FE8D69),to(#F4511E));
    background: linear-gradient(to left,#FE8D69,#F4511E);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(244,81,30,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(244,81,30,.5);
}
.connection__content-item-img.red {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,right top,left top,from(#F76763),to(#E53935));
    background: linear-gradient(to left,#F76763,#E53935);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(229,57,53,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(229,57,53,.5);
}
.svg{
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 360px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 170px;
}
#svg1{
  width: 360px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#svg2{
  width: 360px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button{
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg.js"></script>
<div class="connection__wrap">
        <h2>Заголовок</h2>
        <div class="connection__content">
          <div class="connection__content-item">
            <div class="connection__content-item-img pink">
              <div class="svg">
                <svg id="svg1"></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="connection__content-item-title">
              <p>Текст</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="connection__content-item">
            <div class="connection__content-item-img orange">
              <div class="svg">
                <svg id="svg2"></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="connection__content-item-title">
              <p>Текст</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="connection__content-item">
            <div class="connection__content-item-img red"></div>
            <div class="connection__content-item-title">
              <p>Текст</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="main-btn" type="button"><span>Клик</span></button>
      </div>
```